# How do thumbs up/down work?

Tags: pandora

I understand that if you thumbs up, you get more audio similar to it and thumbs down presumably means the opposite.  Is this limited to the specific station or does it cross stations?

Example, I have a station for Techno and another for Comedians.  However, when I select the Techno station, I generally just want techno music (and only comedians for the other station).  So if I upvote a stand-up routine, will it try to factor that into my techno station?

Also, I can go to a song or artist directly and click "Like".  How does this factor into my stations?

I mainly ask because I have a station with weird songs (like Weird Al, They Might Be Giants, etc.) that began suggesting Comedy routines by comedians I like, but I want this station to only be songs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandora uses your thumbs up / down to personalize each of your stations.

When you thumbs down, that selection (song, comic routine, etc) will stop playing and be removed from your station.  Generally this does not impact your other stations.

When you thumbs up, Pandora will play more selections that are similar to that one.
Generally the likes or thumbs up appear to impact other stations only when content crosses over and applies to both stations.

So, the only time a thumbs up for a comic routine **might** impact your Techno station is IF (big IF) that same comic also performed a Techno song.  You might hear that Comic-Techno song show play in the Techno station some time.

The weird songs station is going to be tough to figure out because comics tend to do weird songs too. The <strike>Edit</strike> Station Details section can give you clues.

Comment: The only options I have are: Share this station, People who also like this, Station details, Rename this station, Delete this station.  Is "Edit Station" the "Station details" option?

Comment: Yes, when you view the Station details you see three sections:  Station Seeds (where you can add variety), Thumbed-up Tracks and Thumbed-down tracks.  You can remove tracks from either "Thumbed-" section. Both of these lists can give you clues as to how the station is controlled.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this limited to the specific station or does it cross stations?

As far as I know from my experience with Pandora, all of your preferences are confined to that station, because if you gave Katy Perry a thumbs up on your Pop station that doesn't mean you'd want her on your Classic Rock station.

> Also, I can go to a song or artist directly and click "Like". How does this factor into my stations?

Pandora puts likes under the social part of their websites and says their purpose is to share your musical tastes, so, no, I do not think that it affects the music I gives you.

To get those comedians off of that station, I'd recommend you [edit the station](http://help.pandora.com/customer/portal/articles/166519-edit-stations-on-the-web)

Answer (score 2):

I realize this question is pretty old but I just had the same question and found this helpful Pandora page: https://help.pandora.com/customer/portal/articles/84832-thumbs

From the website:

> ...**Thumbs are station specific**: rating a song with a Thumbs
>   Up or Thumbs Down on one station will not affect any of your other
>   stations.